# Searching for wrong version of assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013, async-await, nuget-package

I am trying to get the async nuget package for **.net 4.0** to work but it doesn't seem to work. Ive uninstalled the package, restarted **VS 2013**, and reinstalled the package about 10 times now. Ive tried manually copying the file and right clicking add > add existing.

Here is the thing I get the following error each time...

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks, Version=***1.0.12.0***, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So for some reason it is looking for version **1.0.12** but i have only ever installed version **1.0.168** (the latest) so I have no idea on earth why it would be looking for version **12** and I cant find where this setting would be. I tried the packages.config file but it lists it correctly at version **1.0.168**

what the heck!? how can I tell this to look for version **1.0.168** instead!! Please help me!

Comment: Why does my post keep getting edited? I put the full name of the package in the post on purpose, why do you keep removing it? Please stop.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when there is an issue with packages.config. It happened to me a couple of times in the past. Just review your packages.config and make sure that its definition matches with the version you need.

If packages.config is not the issue you can try:

1. Removing the nugget from the solution (right click on the solution and click manage nugget packages for solution) and re-installing it.
2. Update nugget packages in all your projects to require the same version of the assembly. Maybe another project is dependent on the old version.
3. If the reference that you have in the project is for the wrong version, then FIRST uninstall the nugget, then remove the reference from the project and then try to either re-install the nugget, or manually reference the correct assembly.

I also forgot to mention that you can also remove the entry in packages.config, but this is not a good solution (unless you are 100% sure you will only use this library from one assembly), as it will cause problems when difference projects in your solution will need to reference that assembly.

Comment: Already did that... said so above. It shows version 1.0.168 in packages.config and in the .csproj file. Do you know anywhere else to check?

Comment: Sorry for some reason I missed that while reading your question.

Comment: Ive tried uninstalling and reinstalling too... several times. Also the package isnt installed on any of the other projects in my solution. The debugger actually lists which project throws the exception and it is the project I am working on, not a different one.

Comment: So I found where the 1.0.12 version is listed. Under solution explorer > references and click on the reference for Microsoft.Threading.Tasks in the properties toolbox I see a version number of 1.0.12 but it is grayed out and I cannot change it. Thoughts?

Comment: I am really sorry, I thought I wrote that down. First uninstall the nugget package, THEN remove the reference from the project and then try to re-install the nugget package. If the nugget re-inserts the wrong reference (for any reason), remove the nugget, remove the reference, then manually add the reference from the directory where the nugget dll is installed.

Comment: Already tried all that. When you uninstall the nuget it automatically removes the references. And if I remove them manually, then manually add it back in... guess what, still version 1.0.12... no where does it ever ask me to select a version, VS 2013 fills that in on its own and then doesnt let you change it

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the entry from package.config as I mention?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where VS insisted on using a specific version, which was not available anymore.
Restoring and rebuilding did not seem to help.

Lastly, I went for `msbuild dirs.proj` and that resolved the issue for me.